# Create a jQuery Slider with onclick slide functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here's [a link](http://codepen.io/Sairaj/pen/KzxEZP)! to the slider I've created.

```
    /* Create an array to hold the different image positions */
var itemPositions = [];
var numberOfItems = $('#scroller .item').length;

/* Assign each array element a CSS class based on its initial position */
function assignPositions() {
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfItems; i++) {
        if (i === 0) {
            itemPositions[i] = 'left-hidden';
        } else if (i === 1) {
            itemPositions[i] = 'left';
        } else if (i === 2) {
            itemPositions[i] = 'middle';
        } else if (i === 3) {
            itemPositions[i] = 'right';
        } else {
            itemPositions[i] = 'right-hidden';
        }
    }
    /* Add each class to the corresponding element */
    $('#scroller .item').each(function(index) {
        $(this).addClass(itemPositions[index]);
    });
}

/* To scroll, we shift the array values by one place and reapply the classes to the images */
function scroll(direction) {
    if (direction === 'prev') {
        itemPositions.push(itemPositions.shift());
    } else if (direction === 'next') {
        itemPositions.unshift(itemPositions.pop());
    }
    $('#scroller .item').removeClass('left-hidden left middle right right-hidden').each(function(index) {
        $(this).addClass(itemPositions[index]);
    });        
}

/* Do all this when the DOMs ready */
$(document).ready(function() {

    assignPositions();



    /* Click behaviours */
    $('.left').click(function() {
        scroll('prev');
    });
    $('.right').click(function() {
        scroll('next');
    });
});
```

The thing I want to happen is, when the user clicks on left or right image, I want that image to come in **centre**(or middle).
In the current scenario the *click* event works just once.
Can any one help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the use of `click` function that will only bind the event on the current selector ant NOT on the future changes you will made.

You have to use `delegate` function instead of `click` function.

Here is a corrected and working codepen: http://codepen.io/adrenalinedj/pen/JXazmy

And here is the corrected part:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    assignPositions();

    /* Click behaviours */
    $('#scroller').delegate(".left", "click", function() {
        scroll('prev');
    });
    $('#scroller').delegate(".right", "click", function() {
        scroll('next');
    });
});
```

Comment: You should use the `on` method instead of the deprecated `delegate` method as of jquery 1.7

Comment: @jontem `delegate` is NOT deprecated (see documentation: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/). `live`IS deprecated (see documentation: http://api.jquery.com/live/). Also `on` function only binds event on the currently selected set of elements which is the problem here.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ Thanks a lot.

Comment: @ADreNaLiNe-DJ My mistake. It is not deprecated but superseeded by the `on` method. The `on` method supports delegation. Read the "Direct and delegated events" section.

Comment: @jontem You're right, I've missed that point about the `on` delegation. Thx.